# Bringing a gun into a synagogue

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, synagogue, army-military-war

Can you bring a gun into a synagogue? (The question is in reference to Israel.)

Comment: Why do you think the _halacha_ would be different in Israel?

Comment: _I've unlocked this post now that things have calmed down. Please don't go fighting again._

Answer (score 6):

The Gemara in Sanhedrin (פ''ב ע''א) learns out from Parshas Balak that you may not bring a weapon into a **Beis Hamedrash**.But what is the law for a shul, is it the same? The proof against it being permitted is from Shulchan Aruch (אור"ח סי' קנ"א סעיף ו') where he brings that you may not bring a long knife. I am guessing that means sword. This is because Davening extends life and weapons shorten. Therfore it would seem it is Assur. (I am guessing this is the Halacha for America)

The Tzitz Eliezer (חלק י' סימן י''ח) goes into the topic in depth and says if there is no need than it should not be brought into Shul and should be given to the Person guarding outside, but if they are brought in the gun should not be loaded meaning the magazine should not be in the gun, and you should try to cover it with your Tallis. Also if it is loaded it should be covered. This means it is optimal if the gun is in its holster closed  if you are going to bring the gun in. Then he fininshes saying: of course I am talking in a place where there is no present danger but if there is then you may have it loaded and on you but still try to put it down next to you so it not interfere with your Davening. Rav Ovadiah Yosef Shlitah agrees in Yechaveh Daas (חלק ה סימן יח).

We should be Zocheh not to have to deal with theses questions and live like Isaiah says: Let Us Beat Swords into Plowshares. {Why it is in front of the UN I will never know}

Comment: I believe I have seen many Israeli soldiers who come to Shul w/ their guns on their backs...

Comment: YS, I recommend you change the question title to something more direct, less shticky.  One more point: I heard on a Frand tape the question of a shul that would do one davening a year (I don't remember which day) as a Holocaust memorial, and the chazan's gartel would be a rope that had been a noose used during the Holocaust.  For all its deep dramatic effect, one posek felt it ran against the halacha of not bringing weapons into a shul.

Comment: I've heard that an unloaded gun is muktzah on Shabbos, whereas a loaded gun may be brought into shul when necessary.

Comment: Just an amazing addition for Parshas Pinchas. Why did Pinchas only pick up the "Romach" sword after seeing Moshe? see above Moshe was in Beis Medrash so he could not bring it in.